# How to create Android KeyEvent for arbitrary Unicode character?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I'm writing an IME. As you'd expect, it extends InputMethodService.

In onCreate(), I'm obtaining a KeyCharacterMap:

```
keyCharacterMap = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD);
```

I need a way to inject phantom keypresses for arbitrary Unicode characters. My first stab looked something like this:

```
public void generatePhantomKeypress(char[] c) {
    KeyEvent[] keySequence = charMap.getEvents(c);
    for (KeyEvent k : keySequence)
        getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(k);
}
```

It works for letters, digits, and some punctuation marks, but it only seems to work for characters you can enter directly (without deadkey-gymnastics or using the alt keypad) on a PC keyboard.

Some specific characters that cause charMap.getEvents(...) to return null when passed a char[] with a single element whose value is among the following:

- Euro sign '€' (\u20ac)
- Sterling sign '£' (\u00a3).
- It also chokes on accented characters, like 'é' (\uc3a9)

**TL/DR: given a char whose value is some arbitrary Unicode value, how do you convert it into a KeyEvent (or sequence of KeyEvent objects) that, when passed to sendKeyEvent(), will cause Android to act as if you entered that character directly from a phantom keyboard?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an IME doesn't generate key events.  It usually uses inputConnection.commit() to send data to the application.  That API takes any CharSequence (which can even include limited styling).

Comment: Can you use inputConnection.commit() if you aren't using prediction? (I'm creating an IME that uses the buttons on a bluetooth mouse to enter Morse(-ish) code)

Comment: Yes.  The input connection has nothing to do with prediction.  Its a communication channel between the View that is connected to the keyboard and the keyboard app.

Comment: @Bitbang3r , Would you be kind and be able to share a snippet of the final implementation . I am struggling with a similar scenario , It is easy to do control characters but anything beyond basic latin and punctuation seems out of reach .